# What value a Bayesian Net?

Tags: data-mining, bayesian-network

For those of us that work in data mining building predictive models what is the benefit of a Bayesian belief net? I am sure I am just naive as I have not studied them in depth, but what are the advantages?

It seems to me that on the surface, from a prediction stand point, there are typically better classifiers available (I have experimented with IBM Modelers implementation).

From an inference stand point, there are probably better options (perhaps) using a generalized linear model - e.g. confidence intervals. (It seems most implementations require the inputs to be discretized as well).

Further, it seems that one of the uses of a BBN is to produce estimates of the joint or conditional probability, e.g.  P(X1=x1, X2=x2 | X3=x3). Why cant this query just be done in a database?

Hoping to be educated!